# MySQL - Daylight Savings Time

Tags: mysql

For some reason when daylight savings time kicked in, one of my websites that auto-publishes at 12:00 midnight starting publishing at 11:00pm.  Is there any way to set a MySQL server variable to just handle the daylight savings time change correctly?

Comment: Is there any other script involved such as a PHP script? Cron involved?

Comment: I'm with Servicad.  It sounds like somethign else is telling MySQL to publish things at 11.  What else is involved?

Comment: what is the data type being used? value being stored ? cron setting ? programming language ?

Comment: Crons: none being used 
Data Type: DATE in MySQL
Language: PHP (CodeIgniter Framework)

Thank you.

Comment: You should adjust your MySQL timezone settings to allow for DST.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide ...

- the output from `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%zone';`
- the Operating System's understanding of time
- whether the timezone tables were installed for mysql -- see "Populating the timezone tables" in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time-zone-support.html
- which timezone is giving you trouble.  (There are dozens, maybe hundreds, of changes every year, somewhere in the world.)

Comment: I would be very surprised if you get the information you're seeking considering the question was asked almost 5 years ago.

Comment: The list of "Unanswered" is cluttered with stuff.  I want to either answer them, or make the list manageable.  (I probably can't succeed at either, but at least a few answers will be posted meanwhile.)

Comment: @EternalHour -- how did you happen to spot my comment so fast?  Is there some magic sort order that I don't know?

Comment: Each of these questions you are answering sends them to the top of the "interesting" page for all to see if they have that tag as a favorite.

Comment: Ah, so that's what "Interesting" means.  Sorry if I bugged you.